# Put constant text before EditText and TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I want to put some constant text before an **EditText** and **TextView** view widget in android. Is it possible using XML attributes or using any other way?

I want to write Task before taskname field as shown in the picture. Follow the below link to see image.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF0wH.png

Comment: i think you want masked edittext?

Comment: I already did. I can not understand what you are not understanding. Please read the post carefully again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900348/edittext-textchangelistener

Comment: post the screenshot of what you want to do

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF0wH.png see this link. @UmarAta

Comment: that's ok , I saw the image

Comment: you actually need one LinearLayout then make its orientation horizontal, then create two more LinearLayout in one put only one TextView and in other makes its orientation vertical and put all your edittext and textview

Comment: should I post the answer or you understood?

Comment: Thanks for understanding. Yes, I have understood you completely. I also can do that. So no need to post. But I am just wondering that have their any xml attribute or any other way which can do the same task of TextView as a label of EditText field? Thanks in advance. @UmarAta

Comment: that is also possible with edittext , wait i'll post the code

Comment: did you checked my answer @ShaikhHafizAhamed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code to make `EditText` hint to its label after entering text inside it

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/login_field_email"
                android:hint="@string/login_email"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

here is the `TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout` put the below code in style.xml

```
<style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/white</item>
```

Before entering email
[image: Before entering email]
After entering email 
[image: After entering email]

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.github.pinball83.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
                android:id="@+id/masked_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                app:mask="8 (***) *** **-**"
                app:notMaskedSymbol="*"
                app:maskIcon="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha"
                app:maskIconColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                />
```

> How to use

```
app:mask = "8 (***) *** **-**"                     //mask
app:notMaskedSymbol = "*"                          //symbol for mapping allowed placeholders
app:replacementChar = "#"                          //symbol which will be replaced notMasked symbol e.g. 8 (***) *** **-** will be 8 (###) ### ##-## by default it assign to whitespace
app:deleteChar = "#"                               //symbol which will be replaced after deleting by default it assign to whitespace
app:format = "[1][2][3] [4][5][6]-[7][8]-[10][9]"  //set format of returned data input into MaskedEditText
app:maskIcon = "@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha" //icon for additional functionality clean input or invoke additional screens
app:maskIconColor = "@color/colorPrimary"          //icon tint color
```

> For more you can find here https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext

Answer (score 0):

without some sample-code it is hard to answer. One solution may be, to combine a vertical `LinearLayout` with a horozontal `LinearLayout` like this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="constant Text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="myEditText"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="myTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `TextView` with the constant text you want then add a `TextView` or `EditText` for input

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="ConstantText"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="UserText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout as root layout.and place the textview below it.
Add Linearlayout and place your edittext inside it place the linearlayout in the right of textview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:text="Task:" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text1"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Task Name" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Task Priority" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Task Details" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```